# Windows Azure: how do I check the Virtual IP of my service?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role that performs web scraping. I need to determine the IP from which it works when deployed on Azure. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you need the public VIP address, that can be obtained from the Windows Azure management portal.  It's on the dashboard for the selected Cloud Service (about half way down on the right).

Comment: I've found the property, thanks. But no value is assigned. How can I obtain one?

Comment: If the  service is deployed and running, the VIP Adress will be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InstanceEndpoints` property of the `RoleInstance`... you can get all role instances executing by using the `RoleEnvironment` class, and then find the role you are interested in.

[RoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleinstance.instanceendpoints.aspx) - there is a sample showing all of this.

Comment: This only exposes *instance* endpoints, not *service* endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure PowerShell You can use like this -

```
Get-AzureRole -ServiceName "abc" -Slot "production" -InstanceDetails | select {$_.InstanceEndpoints[0].VIP }
```